# Getting values in model use asArray Yii2

Tags: php, arrays, model, controller, yii2

I have send array from view to my controller using ajax, then I want compare it with my model. But I don't know how to get array when use `ActiveQuery` like this:

```
$riderAll = Riders::find()->select('user_id')->asArray()->all();
$tableData = array_diff($tableData, $riderAll);
```

Getting error array to string conversion. Tell me what's wrong in `$riderAll`? please

Comment: `asArray()->all()` will return an `array` having `arrays of result rows`. I would prefer you to do `var_dump($riderAll);` and `var_dump($tableData);`. And see if both are arrays or not. I think yout `$tableData` is not an array. verify it or show the var_dump plz so the question would be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `all()` in activeQuery ..
You have to use `column()` which will give 1-D array so that you can easily apply `array_diff()`

Try this code ..

```
   $riderAll = Riders::find()->select ('user_id')->asArray()->column();

   $tableData = array_diff($tableData,$riderAll);
```

In above you are using `all()` which will output 2-D array so `array_dff()` not be applicable. Ask if other Problem occur..

Answer (score 1):

Try usinge array for select

```
$riderAll = Riders::find()->select(['user_id'])->asArray()->all();
 $tableData = array_diff($tableData, $riderAll);
```

Comment: this $tabledata `array (size=2)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '189' (length=3)`
 this $riderAll `array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'rider_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'rider_id' => string '5' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'rider_id' => string '121' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'rider_id' => string '189' (length=3)`

Comment: You have tried to use the array to the field in the select?.. what's happen

Comment: yes it is an array. but i don't know what wrong when use array_diff have error like this

Comment: Seems your $tableData don't have the same structure of the result of the query.. shoudl be you must manage the result for compare with the $tableData

Comment: The two array don't have the same structure $tableData is Array index , value. while the other is an array Key, value array. for the diff you should use the same format for both the array.  Try extracting the value from the find()n result and add to a pivo

Comment: next question, how to get model an array without name `rider_id` ? thank  @scaisEdge

Comment: You can't with active record but is easy with a simlle foreach scan the content and copy the value in an empty simple array.. .. i hope this is usefule... If my answer is right please mark as accepted and/or rate as useful too.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution I'm create some function to make same structure:

```
function getArr($array, $key) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $row) {
        $return[] = $row[$key];
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**how to use:** `$arr = $this->getArr($riderAll, 'rider_id');`

**then** `$tableData3 = array_diff($tableData, $arr);`

Comment: This is the solution i have suggested.. in the comment... for fair you should rate my answer...